# Regarding to [^ expression what is my misunderstanding point?

Tags: regex, expression, match

I try to search below path using Regex.

```
^.*Aurix_MC-ISAR[^mak]\/port.*
```

But It doesn't work, so I removed expression `\/`

```
^.*Aurix_MC-ISAR[^mak]port.* <-- It works well
```

What is my misunderstanding point? Could you please let me know?

```
Target Path:D:\MCAL_SW_Test\MC-ISAR_AS4XX_AURIX_TC23X_AB_PB_BASE_V300\TC23x_ABstep\Aurix_MC-ISAR\port_infineon_tricore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is you regex

```
^.*Aurix_MC-ISAR[^mak]\/port.*
```

Its breakdown for your string says that

```
^ #Start the string
  .* #Consume everything till next string is found
  Aurix_MC-ISAR #Find this string literally
  [^mak] #Match anything except m, a or k (In your string Aurix_MC-ISAR, what follows just after it is \ which is neither m, a or k. So successful match)
  \/ #Now there is no / in your string further. So it fails here
port.* #Whatever here it won't match as it already failed
```

See **[here](https://regex101.com/r/dB4lO6/1)**

**NOTE** :- From what I understand you are using `\` in your input. So for escaping `\`, you need to use `\\` instead of `\/` which is escaping `/`. Though it will not make any difference in your output because there is not any extra `\` after `Aurix_MC-ISAR\`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: @Hansteve consider accepting the answer if it helped..see [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, that happens. `[^mak]` means **one character that's not** `m`, `a`, or `k`. It matches the `\/` so `[^mak]\/` is **redundant**.

And also, it should be `\\` **instead** of `\/` after seeing your path.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.